# Как выгрузить значения CTR у ключевиков с Яндекс.директ?

Tags: php, яндекс-директ

Возможно ли это реализовать на php через Яндекс API. Может кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 1):

Если без api всяких то можно авторизоваться по curl спарсить ключевики и ctr регулярными выражениями, но это не особо способ надо признать... лучше автоматом всё из xml взять через http://api.yandex.ru/direct/